# Get array of strings from json with json_decode

Tags: php, json, symfony

Seems like an easy thing, but I am not getting the expected data. I want to send an array of strings to my backend and then iterate/do stuff with them.

In the frontend I have:

```
var jsonArray = ["String1", "String2"]
await newFile(JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
```

In my controller, I have:

```
$requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); 
$this->logger->info("File request data is ", [ $requestData ]);
```

My logger outputs:

`File request data is  ["[\"String1\",\"String2\"]"]`

Which is not an array, but a string.

If I do it inside of php with

```
$txt = ["Test", "Test2"];
$json = json_encode($txt, true);

print_r(json_decode($json));
```

The output would be an array. Where am I going wrong or what am I missing? Having the true option in json_decode should return me my array.

Comment: Did you try to use 'false' in your json_decode method?

Comment: Well, if you need to decode it twice on backend means **obviously** that you've serialized it one time in excess on frontend

Answer (score 1):

This

```
["Test", "Test2"]
```

is an Array, and this

```
"[\"String1\",\"String2\"]"
```

is a string. json_decode() need a string as parameter.

```
$jsonString = "[\"String1\",\"String2\"]";
$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);

var_dump($array);

/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "String1"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "String2"
}
*/
```